# How should I go about restarting a custom Apache install?

Tags: apache, macos

I'm working on a server that was configured by a former employee and I need to restart Apache.  Unfortunately, it's not the default install and it's in a different place and apachectl doesn't exist and launchctl doesn't even seem to know that this apache is installed or running.  I don't want to break anything and was wondering if there was a graceful way of restarting this custom Apache instance in order to update the configuration files to account for new SSL settings.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know where Apache is installed, you should be able to gracefully restart it like this:

`` kill -USR1 `cat <apache_dir>/logs/httpd.pid` ``

(Untested, but [based on the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html)).